# Boundary of mesh gives non uniform result

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I wish to extract a boundary mesh but for some reason the `Frontier` option only works on a portion on it:

```
 m10 = MeshRegion[ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}],"MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/10^2]]["MakeLinear"]
 MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[m10], MeshCells[m10, {2, "Frontier"}]]
```

gives

[image]

can't detect the flaw, tho.

Comment: remove `["MakeLinear"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a first order mesh like so:

m10 = MeshRegion[
ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/10^2,
"MeshOrder" -> 1]]
MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[m10], MeshCells[m10, {2, "Frontier"}]]

[image]

Or use `MeshOrderAlteration[mesh, 1]` to generate a first order mesh from an existing element mesh.